# MSSQL Database-level versioning

Tags: sql-server, database, version

Ideally you should be familiar with [MSSQL Row-Level Versioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).

My question is, is there an existing mechanism (or is it possible to create something similar) to get a database version? I would prefer an incremental number (like `ROWVERSION`) but I'd be perfectly happy with just a hash of the last query that modified the database (`INSERT` or `UPDATE`).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? A tracking for everytime database is changed or everytime some data is changed? Please be more specific with what you want to know?

Comment: I want to track every time data is changed...I was specific, you don't change the DB scheme with `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, no? Though with this thought, I'd like to point out that I want to know when the scheme changes as well.

Comment: Then whichpart of rowversion not answering your needs since it is update everytime data is change? Another solution i use to track data change is to update [ModifyDate] everytime application change data. This provided user cannot directly edit data in database.

Comment: I want this at the database level. I can't go looking for each and every rowversion in the DB and worse assume that each table would have such a thing. The requirement should be clear, I need to know when the **database** has changed.

Comment: You mean ANY CHANGE in database?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in that lets you do this.

You could have a trigger on every table for Delete, Insert, and Update, which updates a single column on a table with a single row, adding 1 each time, but this will become a bottle-neck and slow down performance. I wouldn't recommend it.

Alternatively, you could possibly do something with the Last Modified Time on the mdf and ldf files, but you'll probably need elevated access to get to that and it wouldn't be tied to any individual SQL statement. It also wouldn't take into account anything that SQL has got cached and not written as yet, so maybe it wouldn't work anyway.

So, I can't see a reliable and non-intrusive way of doing this. However, I can't actually see why you'd need to - what would do with something that said version = 123456? What if it was version = 123457?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems my options on this are quite limited.